# UNIX Shell Scripting Output

Tags: shell, unix

I'm trying to write a shell script "echo.by" that echoes its arguments as many times as the user chooses. For example, if the user enters the command line

```
echo.by 5 Play it again, Sam. <return>
```

The script should print

```
Play it again, Sam. 
Play it again, Sam. 
Play it again, Sam. 
Play it again, Sam. 
Play it again, Sam.
```

However, I do not know how to print only Play it again, Sam and exclude the first argument. The `$*` command prints everything, so I end up with

```
5 Play it again, Sam. 
5 Play it again, Sam. 
5 Play it again, Sam. 
5 Play it again, Sam. 
5 Play it again, Sam.
```

My script needs to be able to accommodate any script after the first number, so I can't just tell the shell to echo `$2 $3 $4 $5`.

Here is my script:

```
count = 0 
while test $count -lt $1 
do 
echo $* 
count = `expr $count + 1` 
done
```

Comment: FYI -- `count = 0` is running the program `count` with arguments `=` and `0`. If you want to do an assignment, you need to leave out the space: `count=0`. Also, `((count++))` is much easier to write than `count=$(( count + 1 ))` (again, no spaces allowed around the `=`).

Comment: ...also -- quotes; use 'em. `echo "$*"`, not `echo $*`. If someone passed a quoted '*' in your arguments, you wouldn't want it to be replaced with a list of files in the current directory, would you? Guess what happens if you don't quote your arguments...

Answer (score 2):

Just put `$1` in a variable which you will reference later, and then add `shift` to the top of your script.

Comment: This is probably the best answer here in terms of correctness. Considered adding a code sample?

Answer (score 1):

```
 #!/bin/bash
 times="$1"
 shift
 for f in $(seq "$times"); do
     echo "$@"
 done
```

*EDIT*: Changed `$times` to be lower-case as @Charles Duffy suggested. For greater compatibility with other POSIX(-like) systems you might want to change the loop to use the C-style `for`-syntax. The `seq` command is available in NetBSD, FreeBSD and GNU systems.

Comment: `seq` is not a POSIX-standard tool. Better to use a C-style `for` loop since you're already specifying `bash` rather than POSIX sh. `for ((i=0; i<$1; i++)); do ...`

Comment: Edited accordingly. (Also moved to a lower-case variable name -- by convention, all-caps should be reserved for environment variables and builtins to avoid namespace conflicts).

Comment: As I said: I like your suggestion but did deliberately not change my answer. There is more than one way to achieve the same and I think your change changes are way to major for an "edit". I'd suggest to submit your own answer. I'll therefore roll back.

Comment: ...by the way, you're missing an `in`; it should be `for f in ...`.

Comment: Indeed, forgot the `in`. Thanks!!

Comment: ...by the way, you might be amused by the implementation of `seq` used by shbot in irc.freenode.org's #bash -- which counts in human-language numbers. Since `seq` isn't standardized to do any particular thing, an implementation choosing to do something else, after all, is equally conformant.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this using a *C style for loop*  and [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) *array slice* :

```
#!/bin/bash

for ((i=0; i<$1; i++)); do
    echo "${@:2:${#@}}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
times="$1"
shift
for ((f=0; f<times; i++)); do
    printf '%s\n' "$*"
done
```

Comment: Why the overhead of using `printf` and a formatted string, rather than simply `echo`ing the input?

Comment: @AdamLiss `printf` is not overhead -- it's a shell builtin, the same as echo is; its advantage over echo (besides the flexibility offered by format strings) is more consistent behavior across platforms -- POSIX is ambiguous over whether echo takes options, whereas printf behaves the same way across all platforms.

Comment: @AdamLiss ...for a concrete example of a case where `echo` will do the wrong thing, consider `echo.by 5 -n`; the `printf` version will correctly print `-n` five times; the `echo` version will print nothing on a system which chooses to implement `echo -n`.